# UNIX move file name with sysdate

Tags: shell-script, rename, date

I want to make a script in Unix in which I have to move a file daily to a specific path.
In order to avoid overlapping of the file, I want the file name along with the date.

e.g. `mv filename /home/bin`.
How can I add the date to the file name?

Answer (score 6):

```
mv "filename.ext" "/home/bin/filename-$(date +%Y%m%d).ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mv filename.ext{,.$(date +%Y%m%d)}
```